Android: Manifest merger failed, add 'tools:replace="android:resource"' to <property> element
On Android, I am using the latest libraries for Firebase and AdMob:
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.1.0'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.0')

And I get his error when I try to build the app
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':TrenitApps:processDebugMainManifest'.
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : Attribute property#android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG@resource value=(@xml/ga_ad_services_config) from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:22.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:32:13-58
    is also present at [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:23.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:92:13-59 value=(@xml/gma_ad_services_config).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:resource"' to <property> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.

How can I fix this problem? I actually don't have a <property> element in my AndroidManifest.xml

I got the same error when I tried to implement Google Analytics/Firebase to my Android project on Gradle-app's plugin section with id 'com.android.application' and id 'com.google.gms.google-services' then I added property for Manifest to skip this error.

This is a known issue which has already been raised and Google's Devs at AdMob might fix it
You can meanwhile fix it by adding fixes suggested here to your AndroidManifest.xml, as a child of <application>
<property
        android:name="android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG"
        android:resource="@xml/gma_ad_services_config"
        tools:replace="android:resource" />

